# datatables default column sorting

Tags: javascript, php, datatables

I have this table:

```
<table id="datatable" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
     <th>ID</th>
     <th>Agent</th>
     <th>TWWID</th>
     <th>Start Date</th>
     <th>Issue</th>
     <th>Comment</th>
     <th>Overview</th>
     <th>Action</th>
     <th>TL</th>
     <th>Qfinity ID</th>
     <th>MSISDN</th>                    
    </tr>
   </thead>

<tbody>
<?php
//get records from database
$sql_list = "SELECT * FROM `coaching`";
$sql_list_result = $mysqli->query($sql_list);

 if($sql_list_result->num_rows > 0){ 
   while($row = $sql_list_result->fetch_assoc()){ ?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $row['ID']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['Agent']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['TWWID']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['Start_Date']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['Issue']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['Comment']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['Overview']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['Action']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['TL']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['Qfinity_ID_1']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['MSISDN']; ?></td>
    </tr>
     <?php } }else{ ?>
     <tr><td colspan="5">Nema brojeva u bazi.....</td></tr>
     <?php } ?>

</tbody>        
</table>
```

In this table i have sortable heders and first column is defoult sorted ASC, but i want the 3'rd column to be sorted by default DESC.

I include in my .php this js (//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.18/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js)

then I add in .php this script

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#datatable').DataTable( {
        "aaSorting": [[ 3, "desc" ]]
    } );
} );
</script>
```

My table still have sort by 1'st column [ID]

how can i change default sorting?

Comment: Wouldnt it be easier to include your default/initial sorting in the SQL query instead of the JS part?

Comment: yes i try that, and it is sort ok when it loads data. After it is done, then table discard SQL sorting and sort it again by ID (first column)

Comment: Try to clear localStorage

Comment: Can you please help me how to clear localStorage.

Comment: I clear localStorage, even try with other browser but no help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same problem and I solved it with the following code. Please try if it can help:

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#datatable').DataTable( {
    "order": [[ 3, "desc" ]]
  });
 });
</script>
```

Comment: i try to add this code into my page but no change, like any script i add does not affect to the my datatable.

Comment: which col do you want to sort, **TWWID** or **Start Date** ?

Comment: I would like to sort by Start_Date (DESC)

Comment: Thank you, I manage to get this to work. Mistake was that I initialized script before i load datatables.js